# un-focus parent

Tags: i3

When I am using `focus parent` (`$mod+a`) I find I am unable to return the focus to the child that had it before. Instead focus remains on the parent. To remove focus from the parent I have to manually click inside a child container or switch to another workspace and back again. What can I use instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to focus the child, you can use the command `focus child`. It seems that it is not bound by default, but you can just add your own binding. For example

```
bindsym $mod+z focus child
```

Comment: Yes, in the meantime I was also using `workspace back_and_forth` (bound to $mod+b). So two `$mod+b` also do the trick.